Kafka Streams and CompletableFuture (or asynch java api)
I am studing Apache Kafka Stream SPI. I am wondering is there are a way to execute asynch code inside of mapValues method. For example to retrieve data from external store. Is there is a way to interract with Kaska Streams in event-loop reactive style?
    StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilder();
    streamsBuilder
            .stream("SOURCE_TOPIC", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()))
            .mapValues((readOnlyKey, value) -> value.toUpperCase()) 
            .to("DESTINATION_TOPIC", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));
    var topology = streamsBuilder.build()

    var kafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(topology, properties);

how to replace this mapValues code
value.toUpperCase()

with:
CompletableFuture.completedFuture(value.toUpperCase())


Look into Project Reactor or Vertx. Otherwise, sure, use a Future, bit you have to call get() on it

Kafka Streams is not intended to call external, networked stores. The StoreBuilder may be pluggable, but to do what you're asking, you should first stream in that remote store (Kafka Connect, Debezium, etc) into a topic, build a KTable (defaults to RocksDB), then join the Stream against that table, as you get events. This may require using the Processor API, not DSL (or SPI, as you call it).
Primary reason - consumer threads will stop heartbeats if your Future takes too long to complete, then they'll rebalance and/or lose messages.
